# The ring $K[t^2,t^3]$ is not a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I have to show that the ring $R=K[t^2,t^3]$ is not a PID, where $K$ is a field.

Consider the ideal $I=(t^2,t^3)$. If $R$ is a PID then there exist $f(t^2,t^3)\in R$ such that $(t^2,t^3)= (f(t^2,t^3))$. Since, $t^2\in I\implies t^2=f(t^2,t^3)g(t^2,t^3) \implies $ either $f$ is constant polynomial or $f$ is of degree 2 polynomial. If it is degree 2 polynomial then it can't give $t^3$ but what if it is constant?

Comment: A nonzero constant is a unit.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get it.

Comment: An ideal containing a unit (an invertible element) also contains $1$, hence is the full ring.

Comment: Alternatively, any element of the ideal $(t^2,t^3)$ is a multiple of $t^2$ in $K[t]$, hence is not constant.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another take.

Every PID is a UFD.

$a=t^2$ and $b=t^3$ are irreducible elements of $R$ but $a^3=b^2$ contradicts unique factorization.

Therefore, $R$ is not a UFD and so cannot be a PID.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it is a PID, then it is also an UFD and every UFD is normal, (i.e.) integrally closed.
But we can clearly see that the element $t\in k[t]$ is integrally closed over $k[t^2,t^3]$, for instance via the polynomial $x^2-t^2$, but $t\notin k[t^2,t^3]$.