# $R=\{f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x] | f'(0)=0 \}$ is not PID

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Suppose $R=\{f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x] | f'(0)=0 \}$ subring of the principal domain $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I have already proven that $x^2$ is irreducible in $R$. Since elements in $R$ have the form $f(x)=a_0 + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3+...+a_nx^n$ and hence if $x^2=ab$, one of them have to have degree 0, hence unit.

I have already proven that $(x^2)$ is not a prime ideal in $R$. Since $a=x^3$, $b=x^5$, $ab\in (x^2)$ and $a \notin (x^2)$, $b \notin (x^2)$.

Now I need to deduce that $R$ is not PID. It should be easy but I can not see it.

Comment: I think $x^{5} = x^{2}\cdot x^{3}$ and $x^{3}\in R$.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm pretty sure $R = \mathbb{Q}[x^2,x^3]\,(\cong \mathbb{Q}[s,t]/(s^3 - t^2))$ and $R/(x^2) \cong R[y]/(y^2)$ via $x^3 \mapsto y$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yeah, I always forget about these crazy terms after $x^2$. You're probably right.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Well... I'm not so sure about what the quotient looks like now, but it's still true that $R=\mathbb Q+I$ where $I$ is the subset of $\mathbb Q[x]$ with lowest exponent at least $2$, right? Is that really what $\mathbb Q[x^2,x^3]$ looks like? I always envisioned it as being more complicated.

Comment: @rschwieb That part is still true and there $I = (x^2, x^3)$. This ring shows up as a common problem in an algebraic geometry course (show that $\{(t^2,t^3) : t \in k\}$ is a variety). It is clear that $x^3 - y^2$ vanishes on this set and given $(x,y)$ with $x^3 = y^2$ one sets $t = y/x$. From the representation $k[x^2,x^3] = k[s,t]/(s^3 - t^2)$, one computes $k[x^2,x^3]/(x^2) = k[y]/(y^2)$ and $k[x^2,x^3] = k[y]/(y^3)$. It should also be possible to get this by looking at derivatives of the parametric representation $(t^2,t^3)$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Thanks: i'm always in need of lessons in thinking this way, as I've never had any algebraic geometry course.

Comment: Duplicate of many questions; for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412747/the-ring-is-not-pid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ideal generated by $x^2$ and $x^3$ it is not principal.

Suppose that $(x^2,x^3)=(p)$, we have $x^2=ap, x^3=bp$ since $p$ is not invertible $deg(p)>0$, $deg(ap)=2$ implies that $deg(p)\leq 2$, if $deg(p)=1$, $p'(0)\neq 0$ impossible, $deg(p)=2$  and $deg(bp)=deg(b)+2=3$ this implies that $deg(b)=1$ impossible since $b'(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Is there any test to see that it is not principal or you just have to compute it and see that it is not possible to generate it with one element?

Answer (score 2):

Your example showing that $(x^2)$ isn't prime is not quite right: $x^5 = x^3 \cdot x^2 \in (x^2)$. What you want is $(x^3)^2 \in (x^2)$. Then, once you have an irreducible element that doesn't generate a prime ideal, $R$ can't be a PID because this doesn't happen in PIDs. In a PID every irreducible element generates a prime ideal.

Comment: +1 I was trying to come up with a pithy way of explaining $x^3$ is irreducible (or prime) to say just this, that $x^6$ has distinct factorizations.